# Icinga2 is monitoring the same host

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, icinga, icinga2

I'm experiencing a problem where Icinga2 is monitoring the lochalhost for example diskusage even though I set the IP to a different server. What do I do wrong?

Heres my config for one of the hosts:

```
object Host "tellus" {
    import "generic-host"
    address = "10.1.1.48"
    address6 = "::1"
    vars.os = "Linux"
}

object Service "http" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "http"
}

object Service "procs" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "procs"
}

object Service "load" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "load"
}

object Service "users" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "users"
}

object Service "disk" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "disk"
}

object Service "swap" {
    host_name = "tellus"
    check_command = "swap"
}
```

Comment: try and remove `address6 = "::1"` thats the loopback address for ipv6 so you may find your box is preferring that to the 'real' host

Answer (score 1):

Those check plugins are executed locally unless you configure a transport (e.g. using the icinga2 client as command endpoint, or SSH, or any other method to execute checks remotely on the client). The address attribute does not influence *where* checks are executed, it only provides information for specific runtime macros requiring such (e.g. pinging a remote host).

Take a look into the documentation, esp. the distributed monitoring chapter explaining some basics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I use the icinga2 client for remote monitoring? I have been reading the documentation but I find it very hard to understand. @dnsmichi